# How do i specify particular step definition file in Cucumber runner class

Tags: java, selenium, bdd, gherkin, cucumber-junit

I am trying to glue particular step Definition file with specific feature file in cucumber Options and when I run the test runner class using JUnit Test, it was not considered my step definition file provided in test runner class for execution. Also my console prints the code snippet to develop steps for feature file mentioned in test runner class.

I just created JavaProject, not using maven.

My Feature file path (which consist of 4 different feature files):
Project/Feature

My StepDefinition file path (which has 4 different step definition files):
Project/src/StepDefinition

My Runner class file path:
Project/src/cucumberTest

Here, I want to map feature file 4 with stepDefinition file 4 in runner class

My Runner class code:

```
package cucumberTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature/Test4.feature"
        ,glue = {"stepDefinition/Test4_Step"}
        ,monochrome = true
        )
public class Test4_TestRunner {

}
```

I am new to Cucumber, Can anyone please help me how achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting glue path to class instead of package name. Please try with package name as given below.

```
package cucumberTest; 
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions; 
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions( 
   features = "Feature/Test4.feature" ,
   glue =
{"stepDefinition"} ,
  monochrome = true ) 
 public class Test4_TestRunner { }
```

Comment: when I gave package name to glue path, test runner is considering first step definition class file in package but, It supposed to run 4th step definition file in package. Note: My 1st and 4th step definition files has first few steps in common.

Comment: Then you have to create multiple package with different name for each class. But this not good way. Can you add your feature files and classes.

Comment: Try using  glue = {"stepDefinition.Test4_Step"}
Note: Please remember to make the steps definition in each test step classes unique.

Answer (score 1):

When you supply path argument to `@CucumberOptions features` ALL .feature files in that particular package(path) will be executed by test runner. You can't refer to particular file via `@CucumberOptions feature` option, reference is to package(path) only. In order to limit execution to particular .feature file you can do ONE of the following.

1. Move particular .feature file you are willing to execute to a separate package and then refer to that package(path) via `@CucumberOptions features` option. Note that if your do not specify `@CucumberOptions features` explicitly cucumber will try to locate features in subdirectories matching your package structure. In this case, for example if your test runner (ex: JUnit) is in package `cucumberTest` then your feature file has to be on classpath in the folder `cucumberTest`.
2. Mark `feature` or `scenario` within your .feature file with a tag. For example `@execute`. This will allow you to let cucumber know that you want to execute only particular tagged `feature`(if tag is applied to feature) or `scenario`(if tag is applied to scenario) via `@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"@execute"})`. To achieve opposite effect, i.e. exclude particular feature/scenario from execution just add `~`, example `@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"~@notest"})`. You can refer as many tags as you want.

[More information about cucumber tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)

In general I would recommend you to follow standard maven project structure, i.e. put you step definitions in `src/test/java` and your feature files in `src/test/resources`. You can create new maven project from your favorite IDE or from command line tool.

[More information how to get started with maven project.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below code to CucumberOptions

format = { "pretty",
                "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty", "json:src/test/resources/json/cucumber.json" }

Comment: Isn't it to generate html and json reports? My Intention here is instead of running all features and respective stepDefinitions in folder, I want to run a specific feature and respective stepDefinition file. Would you be able to help me, how to map specific files in cucumberrOptions?

Comment: I would rather say , you mavenise your project .Keep your feature file under serc/test/resources/feature .When you run above class , it will ask for the implementations in your step Defn class based on the scenarios in your feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should specify feature as a single element of an array:

```
features = {"Feature/Test4.feature"}
```

Not like:

```
features = "Feature/Test4.feature"
```